# wrong initialization of a short bit by bit - why set incorrectly the most significant bits of the last two variables?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I wrote this program to exercise myself with bitwise operations. In the follow lines of code i try to assign value to three `short` bit-by-bit. Then i print them through `bit_print()` function.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <limits.h>

        void bit_print(short a)
        {
            int   i;
            int   n = sizeof(short) * CHAR_BIT;       /* in limits.h */
            short   mask = 1 << (n - 1);              /* mask = 100...0 */

            for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
                putchar(((a & mask) == 0) ? '0' : '1');
                a <<= 1;
                if (i % CHAR_BIT == 0 && i < n)
                    putchar(' ');
            }
        }

        int main(void){
            short alice = 0, betty = 0, carol = 0;
            int x;
            char c;

            printf("Put 16 bits for Alice: ");
            for (x = 15; x >= 0; --x){
                if ((c = getchar()) == '1')
                    alice |= 1 << x;
                else
                    alice |= 0 << x;
            }
            putchar('\n');

            printf("Put 16 bits for Betty: ");
            for (x = 15; x >= 0; --x){
                if ((c = getchar()) == '1')
                    betty |= 1 << x;
                else
                    betty |= 0 << x;
            }
            putchar('\n');

            printf("Put 16 bits for Carol: ");
            for (x = 15; x >= 0; --x){
                if ((c = getchar()) == '1')
                    carol |= 1 << x;
                else
                    carol |= 0 << x;
            }
            putchar('\n');

            bit_print(alice);
            putchar('\n');
            bit_print(betty);
            putchar('\n');
            bit_print(carol);
            putchar('\n');

            return 0;
        }
```

For some reason, if i input 1111111111111111 three times, executing the program i get the follow output:

```
Put 16 bits for Alice: 1111111111111111

Put 16 bits for Betty: 1111111111111111

Put 16 bits for Carol: 1111111111111111

11111111 11111111
01111111 11111111
10111111 11111111
```

As you can see, the most significant bits of the last two variables, betty and carol, have zeroes in places they should not.
Why?

Comment: Are you reading a newline somewhere where you shouldn't?

Comment: You want to read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn how to help yourself.

Comment: Standard warning: `short   mask = 1 << (n - 1)` is [implementation defined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3): the right side generates a value (a **positive integer** `> SHORT_MAX`) the left side cannot contain. I'd recommend to use `unsigned short` or, if you want a certain width, `uint16_t` from `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `getchar()`, the newline character you press end the end of input gets picked up, but you're not accounting for it.

You'll need to read and discard the newlines at the end of each loop to account for this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <limits.h>

    void bit_print(short a)
    {
        int   i;
        int   n = sizeof(short) * CHAR_BIT;       /* in limits.h */
        short   mask = 1 << (n - 1);              /* mask = 100...0 */

        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            putchar(((a & mask) == 0) ? '0' : '1');
            a <<= 1;
            if (i % CHAR_BIT == 0 && i < n)
                putchar(' ');
        }
    }

    int main(void){
        short alice = 0, betty = 0, carol = 0;
        int x;
        char c;

        printf("Put 16 bits for Alice: ");
        for (x = 15; x >= 0; --x){
            if ((c = getchar()) == '1')
                alice |= 1 << x;
            else
                alice |= 0 << x;
        }
        putchar('\n');
        getchar();

        printf("Put 16 bits for Betty: ");
        for (x = 15; x >= 0; --x){
            if ((c = getchar()) == '1')
                betty |= 1 << x;
            else
                betty |= 0 << x;
        }
        putchar('\n');
        getchar();

        printf("Put 16 bits for Carol: ");
        for (x = 15; x >= 0; --x){
            if ((c = getchar()) == '1')
                carol |= 1 << x;
            else
                carol |= 0 << x;
        }
        putchar('\n');
        getchar();

        bit_print(alice);
        putchar('\n');
        bit_print(betty);
        putchar('\n');
        bit_print(carol);
        putchar('\n');

        return 0;
    }
```